# How should I handle a JSON feed that returns no result?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

Please pardon my first question and general in-experience. I am using FullCalendar 5.10.1 to return events that are dynamically associated with Festivals.

This instance uses the 'events (as a json feed)' pattern from the documentation. In all cases, if there is even one event associated with the Festival dynamically selected, all is well. The calendar displays correctly with the event(s).

However, if the feed does not find at least one event associated with the Festival select, the failure callback is returned immediately. At this point, the Console shows an error, 'Failure parsing JSON'. If the failure callback message is dismissed by clicking OK, the empty calendar is then loaded as expected.

It is clear that I am not handling this condition (no events), but I'm unsure if if it needs to be handled in the feed SQL or the FullCalendar code.

Note that this runs inside of a Bootstrap tab. I've left in some hacky code here that sets a var to the id of the calendar tab and delays the calendar load to resolve a contention issue with a vendors theme.

I'm fairly certain I've not shown the code here in the preferred manner and likely have not described the problem carefully enough. But any insight to this novice would be appreciated.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarButton = document.getElementById('calendarButton');
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {

      themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
      headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
      },
      weekNumberCalculation: "ISO",
      initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
      initialDate: '2021-07-01',
      eventDidMount: function(info) {
        $(info.el).tooltip({
          title: info.event.extendedProps.description,
          placement: 'top',
          trigger: 'hover',
          container: 'body'
        });
      },
      eventSources: [
        {
          url: '/DesktopModules/XModPro/Feed.aspx',
          method: 'POST',
          datatype: 'JSON',
          extraParams: {
            pid: '0',
            xfd: 'Events_FullCalendar_FestivalID',
            FestivalID: '[[FestivalID]]'
          },
          failure: function() {
            alert('There was an error while fetching events!');
          },

          color: '#a1a535',   // a non-ajax option
          textColor: 'white' // a non-ajax option
        }
      ]
    });

    calendarButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
      setTimeout(() => {calendar.render()}, 1);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Feed SQL

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="KnowBetter.XModPro.FeedBase" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="KnowBetter.XModPro.Web.Controls" Namespace="KnowBetter.XModPro.Web.Controls" TagPrefix="xmod" %>
<xmod:masterview runat="server">
<xmod:JsonFeed runat="server">              
 
<ListDataSource CommandText="SELECT
                             EventID AS 'id',
                             VenueID AS 'vid',
                             FestivalID,
                             EventTitle AS 'title',
                             EventDescription AS 'description',
                             EventStartTime AS 'start',
                             EventEndTime AS 'end'

                            FROM la360_Event
                            WHERE FestivalID = @FestivalID">

<Parameter Name = "FestivalID" value= '<%#FormData("FestivalID")%>' DataType="string" />
</ListDataSource>

</xmod:JsonFeed></xmod:masterview>
```

Comment: Do you have the opportunity to change (or request a change to) the code of the feed? It should be returning an empty array when there are no events. It sounds like currently it's returning null, which is really a design flaw. The response type should be consistent in all cases. That's by far the best way to solve this issue.

Comment: Yes, I do have access to the feed. I've verified that the current feed does return null, not an empty array [ ]. I've edited the question to include the feed SQL. It is unclear to me how to ensure the return of an empty array vs null. So far, searching SO has not provided any insight. My thanks for any help and my apologies for the original formatting issues that were cleaned up.

Comment: Thanks. Where is the code of Feed.aspx? I assume there's more than just that data source, or it wouldn't turn it into JSON

Comment: The SQL above is written using a plugin (XModPro) for a CMS (DNN). The feed module this SQL lives in appears to inherit other XModPro code that I'm unable to reference. Unfortunate. I've posted the issue on their support forum over a week ago with no response. At this point, it appears to be a module that is un-supported. So I fear I'll have to find a hacky work around.

Comment: Can you just write your own little asp.net script to run the same query, but transform it to JSON properly? I don't know this CMS specifically but most allow you to add custom code.

Comment: Somebody might be able to, but I don't think it would be me a there appear to references to feeds throughout the XMod Pro plugins (lists, etc.). Even if I did know how to proceed, I'd fear that proper integration to other parts of the plugin would be a nightmare (for me). Having said that, I see that the CMS does include functionality to create in line C#, VB, or Razor modules. <https://docs.dnncommunity.org/content/tutorials/modules/beginning-module-development/organizing/index.html"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll leave my 'solution' in the hopes that it helps someone in the future. I simply used UNION to add a null event record to the feed result so that when there are no 'real' events FullCalendar still works. Maybe not the most elegant or well written syntax, but FullCalendar in happy and so am I.

```
<ListDataSource CommandText="SELECT
                         null AS 'id',
                         null AS 'vid',
                         null AS 'FestivalID',
                         null AS 'title',
                         null AS 'description',
                         null AS 'start',
                         null AS 'end'
                         
                         UNION
                                               
                         SELECT
                         EventID AS 'id',
                         VenueID AS 'vid',
                         FestivalID,
                         EventTitle AS 'title',
                         EventDescription AS 'description',
                         EventStartTime AS 'start',
                         EventEndTime AS 'end'

                         FROM la360_Event
                         WHERE FestivalID = @FestivalID">

                        <Parameter Name = "FestivalID" value= '[[Form:FestivalID]]' DataType="int32"/>
```